# User has no attribute profile

Tags: django

I am currently trying to create a user profile whenever they register and the user is created, the error message shows: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist User has no profile.

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def register(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('blog:home')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', context)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'user/profile.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: did you register you signal in app.py file

Comment: yes, but the problem is that my user does not have a 'profile' attribute, even though I set a OneToOneField.

Comment: all the user who are registered should have a profile. So, check if all the user has a profile including the super user. If not you can clear the database and remigrate everything.